# What's the difference between true and YES in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have read that the two are the same, but my code does not work if I use `true/false` instead of `YES/NO`. For example if I do

```
BOOL matchFound=false;
//...
//logic to change value of matchFound to `true` goes here
//...
if(!matchFound) NSLog(@"I did not find a match");
```

The above does not work properly. But if I change to using YES/NO, it works. Why is that?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. But I would agree with Bas that this is a duplicate (though a good question) so that's moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because YES/NO are not actually boolean values, but instead they are signed char types. This is a relic from the old C days where there was no boolean type.

The article linked below will explain in more details, but in general you should always use YES/NO when dealing with BOOL values in iOS.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/of-bool-and-yes.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: ... with the caveat that in the 64-bit runtime `BOOL` is explicitly a typedef for C99's `bool`.

Comment: Link is no longer working...